# Limit iframe output in comment-meta commentmetadata

Tags: comments, youtube

Often people are posting Youtube videos directly into comment fields under posts,
which is really a nice interaction and I have no problem with that.

My issue starts then, when I see those videos have the typical youtube iframe with over 400 px width.

Now, on a desktop website, there is no problem with that, but when you check that site on a mobile device, you see how the nice responsive theme you created just get messed up with those overlarge videos.

So I tried something like this in CSS to reduce the videos width:

```
.comment-meta commentmetadata iframe {max-width: 600px;} (or width: 100%;)
```

That did not help. All the posted videos are still larger than the site/post.

Anyone knows an easy solution without to delete all the posted videos?

Comment: Can you provide a link to an example post?

Comment: Of course, ivanschneider.com/2014/02/the-bride/ ... and if you minimize your browser window, you will see, how the video is larger than the comment field and thus breaking the design.

Comment: declaring `max-width: 100%;` works for me. it looks like the selector in your example code is incorrect. try: `.commentlist iframe { max-width: 100%; }`

Comment: Ah, man, thanks a lot. Can you write it as a reply, so I can vote-close it? Thank you again, mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declaring `max-width: 100%;` works for me. it looks like the selector in your example code is incorrect. try: `.commentlist iframe { max-width: 100%; }`